# 'Restore Defaults' Preference Page Functionality in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a programmatic method of achieving the same results as clicking 'Restore Defaults' in an Eclipse preference page?

I already know how the field editor system works and preference storage works.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`setToDefault()` of `IPreferenceStore`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore.java.htm) seems to be a good candidate.

You can see the [`EditorsUI`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/editors/text/EditorsUI.java.htm) using this function:

```
public static void useQuickDiffPreferencePage(IPreferenceStore store) {
  MarkerAnnotationPreferences.useQuickDiffPreferencePage(store);
  store.setToDefault(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.QUICK_DIFF_ALWAYS_ON);
  store.setToDefault(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.QUICK_DIFF_CHARACTER_MODE);
  store.setToDefault(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.QUICK_DIFF_DEFAULT_PROVIDER);
}
```

Or in the [method `resetToDefaultSettings()` of class `HeapWalkingManager`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/core/HeapWalkingManager.java.htm#ixzz0PGfOJF9s):

```
/**
 * Resets the preferences controlled by this manager to their default settings
 */
public void resetToDefaultSettings(){
  JDIDebugPlugin.getDefault().getPluginPreferences().setToDefault(JDIDebugPlugin.PREF_SHOW_REFERENCES_IN_VAR_VIEW);
  JDIDebugPlugin.getDefault().getPluginPreferences().setToDefault(JDIDebugPlugin.PREF_ALL_REFERENCES_MAX_COUNT);
  JDIDebugPlugin.getDefault().getPluginPreferences().setToDefault(JDIDebugPlugin.PREF_ALL_INSTANCES_MAX_COUNT);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I must of just missed that, the usual set default doesn't work. You're a life saver! Thx!!

Comment: +1 for you (partly because of your plug-in spy comment to my answer, that feature rules)